# Python: subprocess.call(): why do I need the shell arguments are variables?

Tags: python, shell, subprocess

I read that os.system() shall be replaced by subprocess.call(), so I tried to use that.
I am reading environment variables with

```
parallelrun = os.environ['PARALLEL_RUN']
aims = os.environ['AIMS_COMMAND']
```

and want to run it then with

```
with open(outfile, 'w') as f:
    subprocess.call([parallelrun, aims], stdout=f)
```

I haven't saved the error message, but it seemed to fail somewhere in the subprocess module. I think running it with `shell=True` works but makes the script more vulnerable.
I do not understand why the variables which were specified in the same script do not expand without the shell. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you specify what exactly `parallelrun` and `aims` are? Generally the first argument in the list is the command, and then the parameters. Also, since you already got the environment variables, there is no need to expand them (with using `$` and `shell=True`). Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3172488/5762711) answer also.

Comment: `parallelrun` contains a command like `mpirun` and `aims` the path to an executable.
I wanted to avoid the `shell=True` for security issues.

Comment: Then I don't think there is a problem with the call, but rather with the execution of the `parallelrun` command. It would be helpful if you posted the traceback.

Comment: Don't have it. The thing is that using `os.system(parallelrun + ' ' + aims ' > ' outfile)` works perfectly fine.